# Exporting result from async function in separate js file, importing result in another javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

Trying to build a small scraper. To reuse functionality I thought 'Page Object Models' would come in handy.

In main.js I require multiple small scripts, in the example below there is only one model (GooglePage).
The scripts work. But I would like to know how to pass a value from the google.js script back to the main script.
I want to use the value of the 'pageCountClean' variable in the main.js script to use in the rest of the application.

Have been searching for information about passing values and functions between scripts. For exporting values from pageconstructors, for promise await export function.
But I am lost. Do I have to use Promises?, is the current way of require/importing and exporting enough to create the relationship between the scripts?
Any pointers are welcome.

//////////// main.js

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const { GooglePage } = require('./models/Google');

(async () => {
const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true, slowMo: 250 });
const context = await browser.newContext();
const GoogleUrl80 = https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Anu.nl;

// Cookie consent:
console.log('Cookie consent - start');
const page80 = await browser.newPage();
await page80.goto('https://google.nl');
await page80.waitForTimeout(1000);
await page80.keyboard.press('Tab');
await page80.keyboard.press('Tab');
await page80.keyboard.press('Enter');
console.log('Cookie Consent - done');

// Number of urls in google.nl (using google.js)
await page80.goto(GoogleUrl80, {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
const googlePage80 = new GooglePage(page80);
await googlePage80.scrapeGoogle();
// Want to console.log 'pageCountClean' here.

await browser.close()
})()
```

//////////// Google.js

```
class GooglePage {
constructor(page) {
  this.page = page;
}

async scrapeGoogle() {
    const GoogleXpath = '//div[@id="result-stats"]';
    const pageCount = await this.page.$eval(GoogleXpath, (el) => el.innerText);
    const pageCountClean = pageCount.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(pageCountClean);
      }
   }
  module.exports = { GooglePage };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return `pageCountClean` from your `async` function and `await` it in your main.js file:

in Google.js:

```
async scrapeGoogle() {
    const GoogleXpath = '//div[@id="result-stats"]';
    const pageCount = await this.page.$eval(GoogleXpath, (el) => el.innerText);
    const pageCountClean = pageCount.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(pageCountClean);
    return pageCountClean;
}
```

in main.js:

```
const googlePage80 = new GooglePage(page80);
const result = await googlePage80.scrapeGoogle();
console.log(result);
```